# How to setup SMS configuration in AWS Cognito?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

In AWS Cognito userpool, we need to setup SMS configuration :

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_SmsConfigurationType.html

What are SMSCallerARN and ExternalID ? How to configure them ?

Answer (score 2):

This was answered in the [AWS forums](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=797165&#797165) with one incorrect answer noted below.

Briefly, SMSCallerARN is the ARN for the IAM role that is allowed to send SMS messages (you're prompted to create this if you use the step-by-step setup in the Console).

<del>ExternalId is the developer's account ID.</del>Get the ExternalId by opening the SNS Role that you created for SMS, and clicking on *Show Policy Document*. It will be under the `sts:ExternalId` key.

Note that the documentation says that this is not required (and I don't really see why it would be), but when you try to execute with ExternalId unspecified or empty string through AWS CLI, you'll be told that it's required.

Comment: Not sure where "Show Policy Document" can be found, but the ExternalId is also under the "Trust Relationships" tab when you open the IAM role.